# Bayesian network problem: third day rainy, given first day is

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, network

I've tried searching for this problem online but could not find a solution, hopefully you can help me.

I have three random variables [r1,r2,r3], these three variables shows the probabilities of it raining on a specific day. These dependencies construct the following Bayesian network:

[Bayesian network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOwhg.png)
[image]

I have a dataset containing probabilities telling if it rains on a given day:

[data set for probability of rain for given day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6MWC.png)

[image]

What I am trying to figure out is P(r1|r3) but I am completely lost.

I've tried applying Bayes formula which gives:

$$ P(r1|r3) = \frac {P(r3|r1)∗P(r1)} {P(r3)}$$

However, I am unsure how to account r2 into the equation, do I take in all the possibilities from r2 (that it rains and that it doesn't), and sum them together? This would give:

$$ P(r1|r3) = \frac {((0.226∗0.951∗0.951)+(0.226∗0.018∗0.951)∗0.226} {0.951}$$

Some help could be appreciated how to tackle this problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(r_1|r_3) = \frac{P(r_3|r_1)P(r_1)}{P(r_3)}= \frac{P(r_1)}{P(r_3)}\sum_{r_2=\text{T,F}}P(r_3,r_2|r_1)= \frac{P(r_1)}{P(r_3)}\sum_{r_2=\text{T,F}}P(r_3|r_2)P(r_2|r_1).$$

Can you figure it out from here?

Comment: Hi @Thoth , thank you for the reply. I tried calculating followingly: $$P(B|A) = {P(A and B) \over P(A)} $$
This gave me: $${P(r1) \over P(r3)} ∗ ( {P(r2T) ∗ Pr3) \over r2T} ∗ {P(r1) ∗ P(r2T)) \over r1} + {P(r2F) ∗ Pr3) \over r2F} ∗ {P(r1) ∗ P(r2F)) \over r1} ) $$

When plugging in numbers this resulted in 
$$ {0.226 \over 0.951} ∗ 0.921 $$

Did I understand it correctly? Sorry if my MathJax is horrible, its my second time posting here...

Thank you very much

Comment: Also, the last part equals to 21.8%

Comment: @RawrCheeze you don't need to use the joint probability form of conditional probability, you're given the conditional probabilities directly in the problem.